# Two different .xcworkplace with cocoapods?

Tags: cocoapods

I changed my app's name from `App_Name` to just `AppName` in Xcode, as well as in my Podfile so now it says `target 'AppName' do`.

Looking at my project's root directory, I see there's now a `App_Name.xcworkspace` as well as an `AppName.xcworkspace`. Interestingly, the former is 50KB, while the latter is 70KB. Does anybody know if this behavior is normal when changing the name of an Xcode project that uses Cocoapods?

Comment: Did you call pod install after changing the workspace’s name?

Comment: yea i did. why?

Comment: Then you either didn't rename the workspace ref in your Podfile or you always had that second workspace in your project without recognizing. Check the last modified dates of the xcworkspaces

Comment: The old one is Apr 1st, the newer one is Apr 22. Perhaps it's safe to just delete the old one? In any case the `AppName.xcodeproj` is updating as normal (modified yesterday).